# Group Policy Preferences - Registry: 0x80070005 Access is denied

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have created a GPO to apply several registry keys to a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine in my lab. The relevant keys are within `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet` and I have therefor used the `Computer Configuration`part of the GPO.

Unfortunately it won't apply. The machine complains with:

[image]

I have tried both actions `Create` and `Update` within the GPP, but it does not make a difference.

The Windows Server 2008 R2 machine is a plain vanilla installation without any Windows updates installed. Unfortunately I have no easy Access to Windows Update as I am forced to work in a very restricted Environment. Is anyone are of a KB article addressing this? I just don't see what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because SYSTEM does [not have the permissions to edit every registry entry](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/665f903c-daee-4a2f-8bae-69f36a33162c/0x80070005-when-trying-to-push-registry-settings-via-gpp-on-2008r2-servers?forum=winserverGP).
For this particular registry key, the SYSTEM user only has read access.

This has since been [worked around though](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e02091cc-2e50-4fb1-8e75-e6ea3f5a0719/group-policy-preferences-registry-settings-get-applied-to-server-2003-but-not-server-2008?forum=winserverGP).

> 1. Open according GPO or create a new GPO.
> 2. Navigate to the following location:
>
> [Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security
>   Settings\Registry]
>
> 3. Right-click right-panel, choose Add Key to add "Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc" and give Full Control
>      permission to Admin and SYSTEM.
> 4. Run "gpupdate /force" and test.